# Обрезка строки и добавление многоточия при превышении заданной длины

Tags: javascript

Нужно, чтобы:

- Если длина строки не превышает *maxLength*, тогда строка возвращается в исходном виде.
- Если превышает, тогда возвращается строка, с количеством символов заданным в *maxLength*, и добавлением `...`.

```js
function formatMessage(message, maxLength) {

  let result;

  result = message.slice(0, maxLength);

  return console.log(result + '...');

}

formatMessage('Curabitur ligula sapien', 16);
//   возвращает 'Curabitur ligula...'.

formatMessage('Curabitur ligula sapien', 23);
// возвращает 'Curabitur ligula sapien'
```

Возможны ли варианты без `if ... else` ?

Comment: возможны варианты без if, else?

Comment: Много раз замечал, что если не поставить меньше либо равно или больше либо равно, то бьет ошибку
**return (message.length <= maxLength) ? message : (message.slice(0, maxLength) + '...')**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Правильно говорить "дли**н**а строки".

```
if (длинна строки не превышает maxLength) {
  return message;
} else {
  return message.slice(0, maxLength) + '...';
}
```

---

```
return (длинна строки не превышает maxLength)? 
  message : (message.slice(0, maxLength) + '...');
```

Comment: спасибо!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
function formatMessage(message, maxLength) {
  let result;
  if ( message.length > maxLength){
    result = message.slice(0, maxLength) + '...'; 
  } else{
    result = message.slice(0, message.length)
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]